# npm installation sqlite3 error on Ubuntu Server

Tags: node.js, sqlite, npm-install

I've a problem.
I made a bot on Windows with the module Discord.js and now, i want to run it on my Raspberry Pi 4. My application needs sqlite3 but when i do `npm install` (even with `sudo`) to install all my packages, it returns this (i'm not comfortable with Nodejs errors) :

```
$ sudo npm install
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.11.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-arm64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-arm64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.6.1 | linux | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-arm64/node_sqlite3.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.2/napi-v3-linux-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.2/napi-v3-linux-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.2/napi-v3-linux-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@5.0.2 and node@16.6.1 (node-v93 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.2/napi-v3-linux-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.6.1 | linux | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.6.1 | linux | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.5 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! (node:62288) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/sqlite3/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/ubuntu/.cache/node-gyp/16.6.1/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/ubuntu/.cache/node-gyp/16.6.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/ubuntu/.cache/node-gyp/16.6.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/sqlite3',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.6.1 | linux | arm64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:10:17)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:57:18
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at step (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:54:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:71:22
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at subStep (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:69:33)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:22
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.11.0-1007-raspi
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-arm64/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-arm64" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/sqlite3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.6.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-arm64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-arm64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.11.0-1007-raspi
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/sqlite3
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.6.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2021-08-10T08_46_29_583Z-debug.log
```

my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.5.3",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node ."
  }
}
```

NB

```
$ node -v
v16.6.1
$ npm -v
7.20.3
$ python --version
Python 3.9.5
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you share your package.json as well?

Comment: `npm ERR! /bin/sh: 1: python: not found` -- you need python installed for node-gyp to build stuff.

Comment: Python is already installed :/